# How can I change the value of session from WebMethod which call from another project?

Tags: c#, web-services, session, asmx

I have a aps.net web service (asmx) and I need to access the session of project that contain the web service's (asmx page).

In the project (website) of the web service I have session `Test`, and in another project in the same solution I call to a webmethod that change the value of the session `Test`.

**How can I change the value of session from WebMethod which call from another project?**

I tried this: (but it's not working)

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void ChangeSession()
{
    Context.Session["Test"] = "Some value";
}
```

And I tried this: (Also not working)

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"] = "Some value";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

I create new aspx page and call him from the asmx with `HttpWebRequest`

In the asmx:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("<my domain>/ChangeSessionValue.aspx");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

In the aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Test"] = "Some Values";
}
```